# jQuery AJAX callback after $.one

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have a block of code that I want to execute once on click and then have a callback afterwards. I have tried a few different things; however I cannot seem to get the callback to work. A sample is below:

**UPDATED**

```
$('#button').one('click', function() {
    $.getScript('jquery-validation-plugin-part1.js');
    $.getScript('jquery-validation-plugin-part2.js');
    attachvalidation('#form-to-attach');
});
```

Currently, I am loading some extra scripts with `$.getScript();` within the `$.one();` block. Whenever I have tried to initialize these scripts it has failed. I do realize that `$.getScript();` has a callback function built in, but I need all the scripts to load prior to `init()`.

I have tried `$.done()` after the `$.one()` without any success. Any pointers to what might get this working?

**UPDATE**

So I have added a couple lines of code. Essentially I am loading a form validation plugin and need to initialize it on a form after the script has loaded. The issue with the `$.getScript()` callback is that the plugin has several files that need to be loaded prior to initialization.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code including the `$.getScript();` bit. I’m not following you.

Comment: Added more case specific info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getScript()` is asynchronous.  That means it will finish some time in the future, but not right away.

To know when it is loaded and it's functions are now available, you can use the completion callback in order to run code after the script is loaded.  You can do that using the completion callback in `$.getScript()` like this:

```
$('#button').one('click', function() {
    $.getScript('jquery-validation-plugin.js', function() {
        attachvalidation('#form-to-attach');
    });
});
```

---

When you say this *"The issue with the $.getScript() callback is that the plugin has several files that need to be loaded prior to initialization."* it is not clear what you mean.  Are you saying that the jquery-validation-plugin.js script is itself loading things asynchronously and you need to wait until those things are also loaded?  If that's the case, then you will need some interface into that plugin for it to tell you when it is done loading asynchronous things.  There is not black box way for you to know when it is done loading things without it offering some sort of interface for that.

Or are you saying that you can't initialize the script until some of your things have been loaded?  If that's the case, then you will have to call `attachvalidation()` only when both your files and the script have finished loading.  We'd have to see what you are loading to know how to best recommend doing that.

Comment: So in other words there is essentially no point to separating the script to something like: `$.one('click',function(){$.getScript()}).afterone(attachvalidation());`. I realize that is fairly shorthanded and likely not valid. As for several, I just mean that I often run `$.getScript()` several times for different files.

Comment: @Foo_Chow - you can use either the success handler callback like I've shown or you can use jQuery deferreds (e.g. the `.done()` syntax).  Either will work just fine.  They are different ways of specifying you want to run something when the operation has completed.  Deferreds are more powerful in that they can be chained and put together with other things you are also waiting for, but in this case none of that is needed or helpful so you can go either way.  If you need to make multiple `getScript()` calls and run something when they were all done, then deferreds would probably make that easier.

Answer (score 0):

try using a callback after the script is retrieved:

```
$.getScript('jquery-validation-plugin.js', function(){
    attachvalidation('#form-to-attach');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers given are correct but I wanted to offer one other possibility.

Something like:

```
$('#button').one('click', function() {
     $.getScript("jquery-validation-plugin.js")
       .done(function() {
         attachvalidation('#form-to-attach');
     })
       .fail(function() {
         console.log("Script failed to load.);
     });
});
```

Could also work and allow you to handle a failure.